# Next.js keeps generating 404 page instead of blog details page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, static, contentful

I am trying to generate my blog details page but next keeps giving me the 404 page. I am fetching the data from a headless cms called contentful. Here is what my file structure and code looks like

[image]

And this is my [path]s.js page

```
import {createClient} from "contentful"

const client = createClient({
    space: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    accessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "blog"
    })

    const paths = res.items.map(item => {
      return {
        params: {slug: item.fields.slug}
      }
    })

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({params}) => {
  const {items} = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "blog",
    "fields.slug": params.slug
  }) 

  return {
    props: {blog: items[0]}
  }

}

function blogDetails({blog}) {
  console.log(blog)
  return (  
    <div>
      Blog details
    </div>
  )
}

export default blogDetails
```

I do not understand where I am going wrong. What could be my problem?.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you cannot use the square brackets as a "wildcard" at the beginning of the path and add some other characters after. So you should rename your file as just `[path].js` (without the s after `[path]`).

Secondly, in your `getStaticPaths` function, when you return the object of `params` inside `paths`, name the keys as the dynamic path you've named your file as. In your case, the object you return should be `params: {path: item.fields.slug}`. Alternatively, you can rename your file as `[slug].js` and leave the code like it is.

```js
// [path].js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "blog"
    })

    const paths = res.items.map(item => {
      return {
        params: {path: item.fields.slug} //renamed the key as "path"
      }
    })

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
}
```

You can read more about [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) and [getStaticPaths()](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) in the official documentation.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have made the adjustments but now it is no longer showing the 404 page but throwing an error and not rendering the page. The error it throws is this "Error: A required parameter (path) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /recipe/[path]". When I rename the file to [slug].js it also throws the same error but with /recipe/[slug] at the end

Comment: is `item.fields.slug` a string ?

Comment: I've written it in these two variations, params: {path: "item.fields.slug"} and path: `${item.fields.slug}` and still it gives me the same error

Comment: Sorry, this is not how you make sure it is a string. Try adding something like `item.fields.slug.toString()`

Comment: I just did and it throws the error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined".

Comment: well, it is clear that the problem is with your `item.fields.slug`, as it is undefined when we are inside the map method. Check the spelling or make sure `res.items` is also defined when we map over it.